# Is there a way to kick members without using client = discord.Client() instead of a bot on Python

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I'm new to programming and I have a discord bot, I used client = discord.Client() instead of using client = commands.Bot(...), and now i want to be able to kick users. But I can't see any command using my client to kick someone using their username.I konw it's simpler to do it with a bot but i have already such a big code that I don't want to redo it.
Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to fetch a GuildMember from the Guild then kick the GuildMember. The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) will help you.

Comment: You can' use commands when using `discord.Client`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to `commands.Bot` everything is going to work just fine (if you add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the `on_message` event. But nevertheless here's how to make a kick 'command' using the `on_message` event:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild

    if message.startswith('!kick'):
        args = message.content.split()[1:]

        member_id = int(args[0])
        member = guild.get_member(member_id)

        reason = ' '.join(args[1:])

        await member.kick(reason=reason)

    # If you actually change your mind and want to use `commands.Bot`
    await client.process_commands(message)


# To invoke
# !kick 172399871237987 drama seeker
```

**I strongly DO NOT recommend using this method at all**, just compare how much better, easier and cleaner is with commands

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)


# While invoking here you can actually mention the user
# !kick @some_user drama seeker
# But you also can use the ID
# !kick 761876328716327186 drama seeker
```

It's only **4** lines, 3 if we don't count the `has_permissions` decorator.